# tokenize with delimeter inside and outside of a string with xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I do have an input with randon values in parentheses,square brackets,Curly brackets and values outside brackets.Any type of bracket can occur in any randam position, where all are seperated by delimeter comma.

I have used `<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(test,',')">`

but as comma is present both inside and outside of brackets. It became impossible to achieve desired output. Please help me out

for example

INPUT

`<test>{ST456,PT154},[GH456,JH768],(HJ789,KY456),GH789,PI345</test>`

Desired OUTPUT

```
<test>{ST456,PT154}</test>
<test>[GH456,JH768]</test>
<test>(HJ789,KY456)</test>
<test>GH789</test>
<test>PI345</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xsl:analyze-string` element in XSLT 2 or in XSLT 3 the same element or instead the `analyze-string` function, as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="regex-pattern" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">\[([^\]]+)\]|\{([^\}]+)\}|\(([^)]+)\)|([^,]+)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., $regex-pattern)//fn:group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fn:group">
      <test>{.}</test>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKw9, for XSLT 2 you would simply use an `xsl:analyze-string` element with the same pattern and then remove leading or trailing braces:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="regex-pattern" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">\[([^\]]+)\]|\{([^\}]+)\}|\(([^)]+)\)|([^,]+)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$regex-pattern}">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <test>
                  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^[\[\{\(]|[\}\]\)]$', '')"/>
              </test>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKw9/1